# 502 proxy error on deployment

Tags: java, ajax, tomcat, frontend

I am now working on a Java web project. It works well in local host using eclipse and Tomcat. But when I deploy the war file to remote server (which is also tomcat), one function at front end return 502 proxy error.

The function requests the server that I deployed and the server will further request another remote server. The whole process will take around 2 minutes. I also check the deployment log. It seems that the server is working well except for returning to front end.

Does anyone have similar problem before?

Comment: Post your Tomcat log, and better if has source code.

Answer (score 0):

I just solve the problem by myself. Increasing the proxy timeout works.