# Tomcat 9 Application causing 502 error after logging in

Tags: java, tomcat9, http-status-code-502

I manage a few Tomcat 9 applications that are run on a remote server that also use IIS 8.5. Each site has three environments (DEV, TEST, and PROD). All of the environments are the same but on different servers. Their databases (Oracle DB) are also on separate remote servers. I do not use any other third party frameworks for the sites (such as Maven or Gradle).

One of my applications had an issue where an attacker could access the web.xml through a Multiple Directory Traversal Vulnerability. Some brief information can be found here: https://www.securityfocus.com/bid/63052/exploit

However, I discovered on the DEV and TEST (I thought PROD as well) that the filter we put in place was actually causing the site to not work correctly. You'd put in your user and password and click login and nothing would happen. I seemed to have fixed it on the DEV and TEST environment by fixing the regular expression that my code was testing the URI against. Code:

```
final String REGEX_INCLUDED = ".*\\/WEB-INF\\/web.xml.jsf.*";
...
if (Pattern.matches(REGEX_INCLUDED, URI)) {
        log.debug("SecurityFilter redirect");
        resp.sendRedirect("/errors/403.html"); // /login.jsf OR /index.html
    } else
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

I deployed the new war onto PROD, entered my user and password and it would load. The site redirects to the homepage after login, BUT it doesn't actually load if that makes sense. The response is a generic 502 error (shown below) but the URL does, in fact, say /home.jsp where it should respond with the homepage.

[502 Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BvHi.png)

I've checked the catalina log and I've not found a stack trace or any sign of an error being output. No other logs are useful either in showing what the issue is. I've tried just clearing my cache and retrying, using a different browser, restarting the tomcat service, restarting the site in IIS and nothing.

If there is something I'm missing that you wish to see let me know. BTW, I've tried removing the filter that blocks access to the web.xml just to make sure it wasn't the issue and both with and without the filter, it results in the 502 error.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question: I had looked around everywhere and only after posting I found a related post:

[502 proxy error on deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41770701/502-proxy-error-on-deployment?rq=1)

Their answer helped. The difference between my PROD environment and my DEV/TEST environments is that PROD is on a Proxy. I went to IIS on the server and found the server farm that the site used. I then clicked on the Proxy option and changed my timeout from 30 seconds to 60 seconds. Looks like my proxy was timing out. Hope this helps someone in the future.